# How to make relations between list elements by using particular list element as delimiter

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list that looks like this:

```
list = [4,5,'f',2,6,4,'f',8,6,'f',4,8,9,'f']
```

The list contains values of different types.

I need to separate each sequence of values of similar type. For example for the list above the first association would be:

(4,5) -> (2,6,4)

and then create a list of two-tuples that "connects" each element of each sequence, like this:

`new_list = [(4,2),(4,6),(4,4),(5,2),(5,6),(5,4)]`

This `new_list` would be continuously appended with the next sequences associations until the end of the original `list`.

I have tried using for loops but I don't know how to get the list values until the first 'f' and then continue the for loop from there.

Could anyone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: `itertools` would be a natural choice.

Comment: Shouldn't this be: `new_list = [(4,2)(4,6)(4,4)(5,2)(5,6),(5,4)]`? And what about the rest of the elements in the original `list` -- where do they end up? You need to show a *complete* and *accurate* expected output for your input. And you should show us what you have attempted.

Comment: It looks like `(5, 4)` is missing from your list. Also, how would you continue? Extend this list? Create a list of lists? Would you reuse the last sequence 2, 6, 4 for the next association, or start with `8, 6`? Your question needs much clarification.

Comment: Would you expect `[(4, 2), (4, 6), (4, 4), (5, 2), (5, 6), (5, 4), (2, 8), (2, 6), (6, 8), (6, 6), (4, 8), (4, 6), (8, 4), (8, 8), (8, 9), (6, 4), (6, 8), (6, 9)]` to be the output?

Comment: @RoadRunner exactly! Thats is the output I need.

Comment: @Booboo Seems like OP has clarified.

Comment: @Arthur If question doesn't get reopened, then here is another [solution](https://repl.it/repls/SimultaneousConcernedGenericsoftware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `itertools`. First of all, you can use `itertools.groupby` in order to "split" your list on character `'f'`. Finally, you need to use `itertools.product` in order to generate the product between the two lists.

---

The following should do the trick:

```
from itertools import groupby, product

mylist = [4, 5, 'f', 2, 6, 4, 'f', 8, 6, 'f', 4, 8, 9, 'f']

i = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(mylist, key='f'.__ne__))
associations = [tuple(x[:-1]) for x in [a + b for a, b in zip(i, i)]]
print(f"Associations: {associations}")

for i in range(0, len(associations)-1):
    print(f" {associations[i]}, {associations[i+1]} -> {list(product(associations[i], associations[i+1]))}")
```

And the output would be:

```
Associations: [(4, 5), (2, 6, 4), (8, 6), (4, 8, 9)]
 (4, 5), (2, 6, 4) -> [(4, 2), (4, 6), (4, 4), (5, 2), (5, 6), (5, 4)]
 (2, 6, 4), (8, 6) -> [(2, 8), (2, 6), (6, 8), (6, 6), (4, 8), (4, 6)]
 (8, 6), (4, 8, 9) -> [(8, 4), (8, 8), (8, 9), (6, 4), (6, 8), (6, 9)]
```

Comment: @Arthur I updated my answer :)